# Hashtables not really working

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative

I'm doing some web development, and I'd like to use an associative array in my code. I've used hashtables in other design work, and they definitely do the trick.

However, when I try to call "var coms = new Hashtable();", I get errors stating that there is no class hashtables.

I've read that in JS all objects ARE hashtables, so I suppose if I were to define an empty object, and name it Hashtable, I would be good to go. I'm going to try that n ow. However, it would be nice if someone could tell me how to call an official hashtable.

Answer (score 4):

You can say `var coms = {}` or `var coms = new Object()`

Objects are hashtables in JS

`coms.something = 1` is the same thing as `coms["something"] = 1`

The bracket notation is usually more commonly used for "hashtables" in JS since it's used for associations like `var coms = {"something": 1}` and is used in languages like Python for the actual hashtable/dict representation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JavaScript hash table implementation called [jshashtable](http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable), written by me. Unlike a JavaScript `Object`, it allows any object to be used as a key.

```
var h = new Hashtable();
var o = {};
h.put(o, "Some value");
h.put("foo", 23);
alert(h.get(o)); // "Some value"
```

Answer (score -1):

Or `var coms`, for that matter